# How to configure min.insync.replicas parameter on Spring Kafka Producer?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

On a Java Spring application, I'm configuring a Producer to use [Acks](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#acks) and must set [min.insync.replicas](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#min.insync.replicas) parameter too.

I got it setup Acks using:

```
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, kafkaAcks);
```

but I can't found the `min.insync.replicas` property on `ProducerConfig`. Looking on [Kafka Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/) I not found the property related with `min.insync.replicas`.

So, how I configure `min.insync.replicas` on a Kafka Spring application?

```
    @Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, GenericRecord> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}

public ProducerFactory<String, GenericRecord> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(getProducerGenericRecordConfigurations());
}

private Map<String, Object> getProducerGenericRecordConfigurations() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServerUrl);
    configProps.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryURL);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, kafkaAcks);
    return configProps;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min.insync.replicas` is not a Producer configuration. It's a broker/topic setting.

You can set it at the broker level in your `server.properties` files for your brokers.

Otherwise you can set it per topic, either at creation or by altering it.

Comment: This is the same props of `Replication Factor` ? Aso, I can override this prop on Producer side?

Comment: No it's a different configuration, called `min.insync.replicas`. You cannot override it on the producer side. As I said, it's set on the broker or can be overriden at the topic level. For example, to create a topic with `min.insync.replicas` set to 2: `./bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic test --partitions 1 --replication-factor 2 --config min.insync.replicas=2`

Answer (score 0):

To add-on, for Spring Kafka, you can configure it in

#### 1 application.properties

```
spring.kafka.admin.properties.min-in-sync-replicas=3
```

#### 2 KafkaAdmin bean (Takes precedence over 1 above)

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put("spring.kafka.admin.properties.min.insync.replicas", 3); //This will apply to all topics created by KafkaAdmin
```

#### 3 No configuration

The broker's default of 1 is used as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751187/spring-boot-kafka-duplicated-ssl-properties-in-producer-consumer-admin/74780970#74780970).