# Spring boot kafka duplicated properties in producer, consumer, admin

Tags: spring-boot, properties, spring-kafka

Spring boot Kafka provides in `application.yml` for some properties several placements for the configuration. For example `ssl` configuration:

```
# application.yml
spring:
  kafka:
    ssl:
      trust-store-location: 
       ...
    admin:
      ssl:
        trust-store-location: 
         ...
    producer:
      ssl:
        trust-store-location: 
        ...
    consumer:
      ssl:
        trust-store-location: 
        ...
```

All of them use the same class `KafkaProperties` to configure.
But might `KafkaProperties` be different for `producer`/`consumer`/`admin` beans here?
Am I right that if `producer`/`consumer`/`admin` miss their own properties then they use ones from the base place `spring.kafka.ssl`? And if `producer`/`consumer`/`admin` have their own properties they will ignore ones from the base `spring.kafka.ssl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ssl.truststore.location` [default value](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_ssl.truststore.location) is null. As such, i am using another property, `min.insync.replicas` as example, but the concept is the same.

> But might KafkaProperties be different for producer/consumer/admin
> beans here?

You can configure properties at a granular level if required. For example, for a `KafkaAdmin`, this is how you do it:

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();

    //other configs here
    configs.put("spring.kafka.admin.properties.min.insync.replicas", 1);
    
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}
```

> Am I right that if producer/consumer/admin miss their own properties
> then they use ones from the base place spring.kafka.ssl?

If the bean specific properties is not configured(as per my example above), `Spring Kafka` will look in the `application.yaml`(Common properties can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.admin.properties)), for example:

```
spring
  kafka
    admin
      properties
        min-insync-replicas: 3
```

And if it is not there, the *default* will be configured. One way to find the default is by issuing this command (`min.insync.replicas` is at broker/topic level):

```
kafka-configs.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type topics --entity-name <topic-name> --describe --all

//Result:
min.insync.replicas=1 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:min.insync.replicas=1}
```

The [github's page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/config/TopicBuilder.java) of `Spring Kafka TopicBuilder` also specifies this:

> Since 2.6 partitions and replicas default to  * {@link
> Optional#empty()} indicating the broker defaults will be applied.

which is 1 as per Kafka's broker default, as per [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_min.insync.replicas).

> And if producer/consumer/admin have their own properties they will
> ignore ones from the base spring.kafka.ssl?

Right.